# Splash screen not visible for iPad, only a black screen gets shown

Tags: ios, ios7

I have an universal app. The splash screen loads fine for iPhone but the same is not visible on the iPad. Instead a black screen appears in its place. I have gone through the questions posted in this regard and have followed the steps but to no avail. I am using asset catalog in my project. Storyboards have not been used. The names and dimensions of the images used are as follows:

```
1. Default-Landscape.png (1024x768)
2. Default-Landscape@2x.png (2048x1536)
3. Default-Portrait.png (768x1024)
4. Default-Portrait@2x.png (1536x2048)
5. Default-568h.png (640x1136)
6. Default.png (320x480)
7. Default@2x.png (640x960)
```

Please let me know if there is anything wrong with the dimensions I am using. The options I have selected for the Attributes Inspector for the Launch image are given in the image below:

[image]

Following is the setting for Launch image:

[image]

I added the same launch images to a sample app and the launch screen showed up perfectly on iPad.

EDIT:
As per the suggestion of @iphonemaclover, the problem was solved using "You should also remove any other key suffixed with (iPad) or ~ipad." There was a key UILaunchImages~ipad in the plist which I removed. Now the launch screen is properly visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please delete your derived data and clean the your project.
Also reset your simmulater if you running over it.
Hope it will help.
Also check you have selected Universal App in your target setting.

**EDIT**

You should probably be using an Asset Catalogue for your launch images, which might be what Xcode is expecting. You can see what Xcode is expecting in the General tab for your target:

**MORE Suggestion**

Q: Why does my app launch to a black screen on iPad?

A: Apps that have been designed only for iPhone may launch to a blank screen when run on an iPad. This is caused by the presence of an empty iPad specific storyboard in the app bundle as well as an iPad specific UIMainStoryboardFile key in the app's Information Property List (Info.plist) file. Both are automatically created by the various Xcode template projects if the Universal option is selected.

...

In Xcode

Look for a file named MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboard in the file navigator. If this file is present, remove it from your project.

In In your app's Information Property List

Look for a key named Main storyboard file base name (iPad) or UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad. If this key is present, remove it. You should also remove any other key suffixed with (iPad) or ~ipad.

Finally, test your app on an iPad or in the iPad simulator and verify that it behaves as expected.

[image: Launch Image settings]

You should add your launch image to your asset catalogue, and make sure the setting shown is configured correctly.

If you don't have one already, you can add an asset catalogue by going to `File > New > File`, the look under the `Resource` tab.

Comment: Done that... no change

Comment: I am using the Asset catalogs... otherwise the launch screen for iPhone also won't show I guess.. no storyboards have been used in the project. Only Xibs have been used. Also the app isn't iPhone only, it is universal.

Comment: Problem solved using this line "You should also remove any other key suffixed with (iPad) or ~ipad." There was a key UILaunchImages~ipad in the plist which I removed. Thanks for the help. Adding this to edit.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not loading an image in your slash screen do you get the white view? If you're not getting, then your view is not loaded. That is why you're getting a black screen.

Comment: No, I am adding the image... Still getting black screen

Comment: if your still facing the issue, i suggest you to delete the view in your splash, and a new view and give a back ground colour to it. if you get the colour you given to the view, add a image view into it. i hop that will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related to most people's problems but I would like to add another possible issue. I had the same problem with my project. I could see my iPad images in X-Code but what I missed was that the title underneath was "unassigned" and not "iPad Portrait" (this was probably because it was a boilerplate React Native project that was initially configured only for iPhone).

After making my app universal, I needed to recreate my LaunchImage set which then had designated placeholders for iPad. I re-added all my images, assigned the new Launch Image set, clean, build and it was fixed. Hopefully it saves someone else some time.